# How to store dates and associated values in PHP correctly?

Tags: php, arrays, date, datetime, int

I have the following type of data (this is a simplified version):

```
//date            //int
2014-01-29        4
2014-02-04        5
2014-02-07        2
2014-02-16        1
```

I want to store this on a per month basis, so along these lines:

```
2014-01 -> 4
2014-02 -> 8
```

Currently the only way I can think to do this is using a 2D array of strings and ints:

```
$date_data[0][0] = '2014-01';
$date_data[0][1] = 4;

$date_data[1][0] = '2014-02';
$date_data[1][1] = 8;
```

What's the correct way to store data of this type such that I can then loop through it in date order.

Comment: the first example storage is correct, after that its a question on efficiently selecting the data you want

Answer (score 3):

You can use strings as your Array indexes.

```
$date_data['2014-01'] = 4;
$date_data['2014-02'] = 8;
```

Then you can access the array by date.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an associative array -

```
$date_data(
    0 => array('date'=>'2014-01', 'count'=> 4),
    1 => array('date'=>'2014-02', 'count'=> 8)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through the dates and their values and group them by year and month and increment the total value. You can sort it afterwards if necessary.

```
<?php
$dates = array(
  '2014-01-29' => 4,
  '2014-02-04' => 5,
  '2014-02-07' => 2,
  '2014-02-16' => 1,
);

$values = array();
foreach ($dates as $date => $value) {
    $dt = new DateTime($date);
    $key = sprintf('%s-%s', $dt->format('Y'), $dt->format('m'));
    if (!isset($values[$key])) {
        $values[$key] = 0;
    }
    $values[$key] += $value;
}

print_r($values);
// Array ( [2014-01] => 4 [2014-02] => 8 )
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HVrprE)